# Keep socketio and nodejs connection on even when the app is not running

Tags: android, socket.io, android-webview

I have a chat system in which the socketio client sends an id to the node server after successful connection. So when the user is using the app they are connected to the node server  all the time but when the app is closed the connection closes as well. So what i want is to keep the client connected to the server even when the app is not running. I am using Webview for the app.

Question: How to connect to the node server with socketio and send some data with it using javascript, when the app is not running?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Build an endpoint in node to generate client ids, and when the client connects issue your own ID to them, and associate the socketio ID with your own ID. Then refer to your own ID in entities. Using a library's ID as your own will be a pain later in any case, and this way when the client re-connects, it can provide the ID you custom issued to them, and pick up where it left off. This makes reconnecting OK and means you don't have to architect around this problem.

I say all this because it would be *very hard* to maintain 100% uptime to the extent that the connection would never close. Impractically so. If the android app restarts, then all the state will be reset if you rely on these transient IDs provided by socketio. If the backend restarts, any proxies glitch etc. Then you will be back to square one.

That being said, I would build two node servers - a socket server, which does nothing but accept connections and forward data, and a second server which can restart all day long, and which is responsible for invoking the first server to send data.

If you wanted to scale this out, you might have lots and lots of the socket servers, have them bind to a queuing system such as rabbitmq, and subscribe to events for the clients they have connections with, when they get events they can write them through to the socket. Then have your other controlling service publish events to the queuing system to issue events to the sockets. This way you could fully decouple the redeploys of the business logic from the servers maintaining connections to your android clients.

Yet another solution could be to use something such as https://www.pubnub.com/ which will handle most of these problems for you.

Best luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right in that aspect, but I'm sorry bcoz i really messed up the question. What i wanted to know is much simple than what i asked. The id which the client sends to the server is fixed or static to that user so thats not the problem. The problem is that when the app closes or restarts  the id is deleted from the server so now the server has no clue of that client. So what i wanted to know is how to connect to the server again(and eventually send that same id) in the background when the app is not running using socketio.

Comment: @atx, you want the android app to maintain a connection even while it is in the background? From what I understand you may be able to get a few moments here and there where you can reconnect and slurp some events down, but you won't be able to keep it alive 24/7. I'd look into the lifecycle hooks available to the activity, around when it is paused and resumed.

Comment: The connection is all ok when the activity/app is paused and resumed, the problem occurs when the app is closed by the user. I think calling a js function which connects to the server, `var socket = io('0.0.0.0:8000')`, using Android Service running in the background will do the trick(but not sure). What do you think, Catalyst?

Comment: Reading around, I would do that, but use a service https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html

Comment: > Declares a service (a Service subclass) as one of the application's components. Unlike activities, services lack a visual user interface. They're used to implement long-running background operations or a rich communications API that can be called by other applications.